# Is it possible to pass through an Email Address to the AWS Cognito Hosted Fields UI

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to pass through an Email Address to the AWS Cognito Hosted Fields UI

I have set up AWS Cognito User pools and app credentials. I can get the Hosted Field UI to login successfully and return to the callback URL.

What I am trying to do is auto fill the email address automatically on the Hosted Fields UI rather than ask the user to fill this in. Is this possible via a query parameter to the Hosted UI URL, JS API or any other mechanism?

Reason for this is that from my application, I ask the user for the email address. If they are configured to be authenticated  via Cognito, I will be redirecting them to the cognito Hosted UI page and I would like the email address to already be pre filled based on what they entered.

I tried going through the documentation on AWS, options on the AWS Console and various samples without much luck. The only way I found to be able to do it was create my own custom login and use the AWS Amplify JS API to do the `signIn`. I am trying not do build the whole sign in flow myself as there are MFA and other requirements which are handled just the way I want with the Hosted UI.

Comment: You may find this helpful - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/userinfo-endpoint.html

Comment: @Srini - Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm trying to do something very similar.

Comment: @Sen I couldnt do it through the Cognito hosted UI, however I used the amplify ui and then was able to just use js to set the password as the components are native client side and not iframed. If you need any more details, feel free to ping me and I am happy to share some insights or walk you through my design